# Flex/Flash 4 datagrid displays raw xml

Tags: java, flash, soap, flex4

Problem: Flex/Flash4 client (built with FlashBuilder4) displays the xml sent from the server exactly as is - the datagrid keeps the format of the xml. I need the datagrid to parse the input and place the data in the correct rows and columns of the datagrid.

flow: click on a date in the tree and it makes a server request for batch information in xml form. Using a CallResponder I then update the datagrid's dataProvider.

[code]

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        [Bindable]public var selectedTreeNode:XML;
        public function taskTreeChanged(event:Event):void {
            selectedTreeNode=Tree(event.target).selectedItem as XML;
            var searchHubId:String = selectedTreeNode.@hub;
            var searchDate:String = selectedTreeNode.@lbl;
            if((searchHubId == "") || (searchDate == "")){
                return;
            }
        findShipmentBatches(searchDate,searchHubId);
        }
        protected function findShipmentBatches(searchDate:String, searchHubId:String):void{
            findShipmentBatchesResult.token = actWs.findShipmentBatches(searchDate, searchHubId);
        }
        protected function updateBatchDataGridDP():void{
        task_list_dg.dataProvider = findShipmentBatchesResult.lastResult;
    }
]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <actws:ActWs id="actWs" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="findShipmentBatchesResult" result="updateBatchDataGridDP()"/>
</fx:Declarations> 

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="task_list_dg" width="100%" height="95%" paddingLeft="0" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Receiving date" dataField="rd"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Msg type" dataField="mt"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="SSD" dataField="ssd"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Shipping site" dataField="sss"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="File name" dataField="fn"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Batch number" dataField="bn"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

//xml example from server
<batches>
    <batch>
        <rd>2010-04-23 16:31:00.0</rd>
        <mt>SC1REVISION01</mt>
        <ssd>2010-02-18 00:00:00.0</ssd>
        <sss>100000009</sss>
        <fn>Revision 1-DF-Ocean-SC1SUM-Quanta-PACT-EMEA-Scheduled Ship Date 20100218.csv</fn>
        <bn>10041</bn>
    </batch>
<batches>
```

[/code]

and the xml is pretty much displayed exactly as is shown in the example above in the datagrid columns...

I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: dude, seriously, work out the code tag, this is not answerable..

Comment: I was in the process of working out the tags, anyway here is the output. thnx

Comment: actually it wasn't the tabs it was the tab space before each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a simplified version of your sample using a simple xml literal, and it works fine for me..

here's what I've got

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function onCreationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            task_list_dg.dataProvider = data..batch;
        }

        private var data:XML = //xml example from server
            <batches>
            <batch>
                <rd>2010-04-23 16:31:00.0</rd>
                <mt>SC1REVISION01</mt>
                <ssd>2010-02-18 00:00:00.0</ssd>
                <sss>100000009</sss>
                <fn>Revision 1-DF-Ocean-SC1SUM-Quanta-PACT-EMEA-Scheduled Ship Date 20100218.csv</fn>
                <bn>10041</bn>
            </batch>
            </batches>;



    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="task_list_dg" width="100%" height="95%" paddingLeft="0" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Receiving date" dataField="rd"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Msg type" dataField="mt"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="SSD" dataField="ssd"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Shipping site" dataField="sss"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="File name" dataField="fn"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Batch number" dataField="bn"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Are you sure your data is arriving in the format you're suggesting? 
(check the Data/Services tab in FB)

What do you mean by "displays the xml sent from the server exactly as is - the datagrid keeps the format of the xml" ? does it dump xml content in the grid cells?

**Edit**: Have you tried doing this?

```
protected function updateBatchDataGridDP():void{
    task_list_dg.dataProvider = findShipmentBatchesResult.lastResult..batch;
}
```

Comment: exactly the datagrid displays the xml in raw format. The entire xml content for each column.

Comment: the Data/Services tab looks like findShipmentBatches(searchDate:string, searchHubId: string_: string

should the return type be xml?

Comment: There seem to be many return type options when I try XML* I would presume a simple String would have sufficed then the client side would be intelligent enough to parse the content.

Comment: added suggestion (Edit) in my response.. (lastResult..batch)

Comment: ben I wanted to get back to you but some more urgent issues have come up - i need to squash them first! I promise to get back asap! ;) btw looks like it can work and no i havne't tried that way!

Comment: So finally back ;) anyway, I gave that way a bash I just get a Flash / Flex Error 1061 error. So I presume something is wrong. Secondly I have tried to change the format to 
<node rd="xxx0" sss="xxx0" etc="etc0" /> 
<node rd="xxx1" sss="xxx1" etc="etc1" />
<node rd="xxx2" sss="xxx2" etc="etc2" />
This approach also seems not to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: btw the datagrid displays the exact xml text as above in one row and is repeated for every column.

Comment: a post lower Ben mentions the use of the @ sign in the grid. So please don't be a dumb ass like me and forget it.

Comment: ahh. Well i'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

had to resort to this monstrosity ----> is there a better way???

```
        protected function updateBatchDataGridDP():void{
            var batches:XML = new XML(findShipmentBatchesResult.lastResult);
            task_list_dg.dataProvider = batches.batch;
            var task_list_col1:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col1.dataField = "@rd";
            task_list_col1.headerText = "Receiving date";
            var task_list_col2:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col2.dataField = "@mt";
            task_list_col2.headerText = "Msg type";
            var task_list_col3:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col3.dataField = "@ssd";
            task_list_col3.headerText = "SSD";
            var task_list_col4:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col4.dataField = "@sss";
            task_list_col4.headerText = "Shipping site";
            task_list_status.text = batches.batch.@sss;
            var task_list_col5:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col5.dataField = "@fn";
            task_list_col5.headerText = "File name";
            var task_list_col6:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();
            task_list_col6.dataField = "@bn";
            task_list_col6.headerText = "Batch number";
            var myColumns:Array = new Array();
            myColumns.push(task_list_col1);
            myColumns.push(task_list_col2);
            myColumns.push(task_list_col3);
            myColumns.push(task_list_col4);
            myColumns.push(task_list_col5);
            myColumns.push(task_list_col6);
            task_list_dg.columns = myColumns;
        }
```

with this xml structure:

```
<batches>
    <batch rd="2010-04-23 16:31:00.0" mt="SC1REVISION01" ssd="2010-02-18 00:00:00.0" sss="Quanta" fn="Revision 1-DF-Ocean-SC1SUM-Quanta-PACT-EMEA-Scheduled Ship Date 20100218.csv" bn="SHA201004230033" />
    <batch rd="2010-04-23 16:32:14.0" mt="SC1" ssd="2010-02-11 00:00:00.0" sss="Quanta" fn="DF-Ocean-SC1SUM-Quanta-PACT-EMEA-Scheduled Ship Date 20100211.csv" bn="SHA201004230043" />
    <batch rd="2010-04-23 16:35:51.0" mt="PRESHIP" ssd="2010-02-15 00:00:00.0" sss="Quanta" fn="DF-Ocean-PRESHIPSUM-Quanta-PACT-EMEA-Scheduled Ship Date 20100215.csv" bn="SHA201004230045" />
</batches>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do all, that's not right.
You can specify and @attribute in the column tags:
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Receiving date" dataField="@rd"/>

Comment: oh man this is the reason ..... my grid doesn't have the @ sign! and the example I copied off the internet makes use of it. yes mate now I see my mistake! please make another answer and Ill assign the right answer to you :)

Comment: yes it was the @ sign -> i think I need rest. thanks so much mate.